# Get Value of Custom Field

Tags: functions, customization

I use a dropdownbox to show all custom types ('abschreibungstabelle'). It works fine. But now, I want to show the value of the custom field 'nutzungsdauer' in my input-field. Any ideas?

```
  <input type="text" class="text-input" placeholder="Nutzungsdauer" value="" name="nutzungsdauer" id="nd">
```

function.php

```
 function afa_type_dropdown( $post_type )
{
$posts = get_posts(
    array(
        'post_type'  => $post_type,
        'numberposts' => -1
    )
);
if( ! $posts ) return;

$out = '<select id="afa_select"><option>Anlagegut auswählen</option>';
foreach( $posts as $p )
{
    $out .= '<option value="' . get_permalink( $p ) . '">' . esc_html( $p->post_title ) . '</option>';  
 }
$out .= '</select>';
return $out;
}
```

Comment: Please add more details regarding what is `nutzungsdauer` and how is it related to the above drop down

Comment: nutzungsdauer is the name of a custom field. Every post of the post type 'abschreibungstabelle' has one custom field called nutzungsdauer. The custom field contains a value like 10 or 23 or 44 or ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the `$posts` are the posts of post_type `abschreibungstabelle`, you can get the custom field values by using **[`get_post_custom_values`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom_values)**

```
if( ! $posts ) return;

$out = '<select id="afa_select"><option>Anlagegut auswählen</option>';
foreach( $posts as $p )
{
  $custom_field_value = get_post_custom_values( 'nutzungsdauer', $p->ID );
  // Now you can use the value the way you want
    $out .= '<option value="' . get_permalink( $p->ID ) . '">' . esc_html( $p->post_title ) . '</option>';  
 }
$out .= '</select>';
return $out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I´ve tried to this. But I only get an array of the custom fields. What is the problem?

```
function afa_type_dropdown( $post_type )
{
$posts = get_posts(
array(
    'post_type'  => 'abschreibungstabelle',
    'numberposts' => -1,
)
);
if( ! $posts ) return;

 $out = '<select id="afa_select"><option>Anlagegut auswählen</option>';
 foreach( $posts as $p )
{

$nd = get_post_custom_values('nutzungsdauer', $p->ID);
// Now you can use the value the way you want
$out .= '<option value="' . get_permalink( $p->ID ) . '">' . esc_html( $p->post_title )    ." ".  $nd . '</option>';  
}
$out .= '</select>';
return $out;
}
```